# Grouping items in lists based on keys

Tags: python, algorithm

Given an iteratable with (key, value) pairs, return a dict with the keys and a list with all values for each specific key, including duplicates.

Example:

```py
Input: [
    ('germany', 'john'), 
    ('finland', 'olavi'), 
    ('france', 'alice'), 
    ('germany', 'gerd'),
    ('germany', 'john')
]

Output: {
    'germany': ['john', 'gerd', 'john'], 
    'finland': ['olavi'], 
    'france': ['alice']
}
```

I am looking for some elegant solutions. I also posted what I had in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just one of the many possible solutions.

```
input_data = [
    ('germany', 'john'), 
    ('finland', 'olavi'), 
    ('france', 'alice'), 
    ('germany', 'gerd'),
    ('germany', 'john')
]

output_data = {}
for k, v in input_data:
    output_data[k] = output_data.get(k, []) + [v]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input_data=[
    ('germany', 'john'), 
    ('finland', 'olavi'), 
    ('france', 'alice'), 
    ('germany', 'gerd'),
    ('germany', 'john')
]
# Creating unique Keys with list as values
output={key:[] for key in dict.fromkeys([i[0] for i in input_data])}
# Fill the Lists with the correspondig Keys
for key,value in input_data:
    output[key].append(value)
print(output)
```

Comment: Your `dict.fromkeys` line looks redundant. I suggest simplifying to `output={ country: [] for country,_ in input_data}`. (I'm guessing you wrote that line to avoid `output = dict.fromkeys(..., [])` since that would use the same list for all keys, but since you end up using a dict comprehension, then there is not much point in using `dict.fromkeys`)

Answer (score 1):

Another variant:

```
given = [
    ('germany', 'john'), 
    ('finland', 'olavi'), 
    ('france', 'alice'), 
    ('germany', 'gerd'),
    ('germany', 'john')
]
    
result = dict()
for k, v in given:
    try:
        result[k].append(v)
    except KeyError:
        result[k] = [v]
```

Edit: Picking up the suggestion in the comments. It's one line shorter and perhaps the easiest to read from all variants:

```
result = dict()
for k, v in given:
    if k not in result:
        result[k] = []
    result[k].append(v)
```

Comment: You can use `if k in result:` instead of `try: ... except:`

Comment: @Stef, you are right. And what Robert wrotes is technical considered more pythonic, see [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-EAFP).

Comment: @Chris I'm not convinced. Using try/except might be "more pythonic" for a function which is passed a dictionary and doesn't know whether a key is in it or not. But here we're building the dictionary ourselves, and expecting the keys to be missing from it.

Comment: It is a controversial subject, indeed and at the end of the day a personal preference. I also usually go with if tests. In this case its basically the same lines of code, so it doesn't matter, but usually I find the try except looks much bigger and more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will usefull.

```
 input=[
        ('germany', 'john'), 
        ('finland', 'olavi'), 
        ('france', 'alice'), 
        ('germany', 'gerd'),
        ('germany', 'john')
    ]
    
    final_dict = {}
    key = []
    for inp in input:
        if inp[0] not in key:
           key.append(inp[0])
           final_dict[inp[0]] = [inp[1]]
        else:
            final_dict[inp[0]].append(inp[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can try this - using *dict.setdefault*:

```py
data= [
    ('germany', 'john'), 
    ('finland', 'olavi'), 
    ('france', 'alice'), 
    ('germany', 'gerd'),
    ('germany', 'john')
]

groups = {}

for country, name in data:
    groups.setdefault(country, []).append(name)

print(groups)
```

Output:

```
{'germany': ['john', 'gerd', 'john'], 'finland': ['olavi'], 'france': ['alice']}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here:

```
import collections
from typing import Iterable, Tuple, Dict, List

def group_data(matches: Iterable[Tuple[str, str]]) -> Dict[str, List[str]]:
    res = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in matches:
        res[key].append(value)
    return dict(res)
```

Testing

```
input_data = [
    ('germany', 'john'), 
    ('finland', 'olavi'), 
    ('france', 'alice'), 
    ('germany', 'gerd'),
    ('germany', 'john')
]

print(group_data(input_data))
```

Result

```
{'germany': ['john', 'gerd', 'john'], 'finland': ['olavi'], 'france': ['alice']}
```